# Remote Redis Server from Resque Standalone

Tags: ruby, redis, resque, worker

I want to run Resque workers on different servers, getting jobs from one Redis server. I know how to configure it in a Rails application, but the problem is I am using standalone Resque (https://github.com/dcestari/resque-standalone-sample) on every Server.

So my question is, how can I do this without installing a Rails application and is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: also it's a little deterring to answer questions for a user that has never accepted an answer before, you should really make it a point to accept them when they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell Resque where Redis lives:

```
Resque.configure do |config|

  # Set the redis connection. Takes any of:
  #   String - a redis url string (e.g., 'redis://host:port')
  #   String - 'hostname:port[:db][/namespace]'
  #   Redis - a redis connection that will be namespaced :resque
  #   Redis::Namespace - a namespaced redis connection that will be used as-is
  #   Redis::Distributed - a distributed redis connection that will be used as-is
  #   Hash - a redis connection hash (e.g. {:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379, :db => 0})
  config.redis = 'redis://someserverip:port:db/namespace'

end
```

Comment: and in which file do I need to write it? will it work for standalone resque?

Comment: you can do this all in one file if you prefer.  This isn't rails as you said so "where this goes", isn't as important.

Comment: When I try to write it e.g. to the multiplier.rb from https://github.com/dcestari/resque-standalone-sample, it does not work. or do I really need to create a config-file?